# How do I calculate a multiple of a page size which is larger than an arbitrary value?

Tags: c, memory

I'm facing a bug in a system in which someone is corrupting memory that I've allocated. I'm hopeful that I can mprotect the memory as read-only so that I can catch the corruptor via a seg fault when they try to write to the protected memory.

My allocation used to look like this:

```
MyObject *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(MyObject));
```

My plan is to write the memory at `ptr` then call `mprotect` on it when I'm done to make the memory read-only.

I initially planned to use `pvalloc` but noticed that, while it is super simple to use, it is deprecated. Assuming that I don't want to use `pvalloc`, how can I replace its use with [aligned_alloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/aligned_alloc)? If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, I have to calculate my buffer_size as a multiple of the page size, but larger than the arbitrary `sizeof(MyObject)` size.

```
static size_t const page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

static size_t const buffer_size = // <----- Help;

MyObject *ptr = aligned_alloc(page_size, buffer_size);
memset(pcj, 0, buffer_size);
// Modify the memory as needed.
// Now, protect it:
mprotect(ptr, buffer_size, PROT_READ);
```

Can someone help me fill in `// <----- Help` above? (Note that this is C code, not C++.)

Comment: Have you tried building and running with a *sanitizer*? For example if you build with GCC or Clang you could use `-g -fsanitize=address` to catch out-of-bounds access and learn its location in your code. There's also tools like Valgrind that can help you as well. I assume that you already build with extra warning enabled (at least `-Wall -Wextra`) as some cases might even be caught by the compiler itself.

Comment: _Side note:_ Have you tried compiling with `-fsanitize=address`? Also, have you tried running under `gdb` and setting a hardware watchpoint? There are a number of other methods as well.

Comment: The "usual suspect" for heap allocations is the allocation that is immediately before the corrupted one in memory. That is, if the heap is: `allocA | allocB`. If `B` is yours and is being corrupted, it's usually because `A` is running over. It should be possible to use the `malloc` [et. al.] hooks and remember who/what did the `allocA`. Then, some static analysis and/or code inspection could show something.

Comment: `(sizeof MyObject + page_size - 1) / page_size * page_size` should be the proper `buffer_size`

Comment: Note that `malloc` will use anonymous `mmap` (vs. `sbrk`) for large allocations (e.g. >1MB). So, if you want to `mprotect`, it may be easier with an explicit `mmap` that you control. Also, with `mmap`, you could try an explicit mapping address that is at some high address, far removed from the heap area. Then, do you still get corruption? If so, it's something riffing off of your pointer vs an unrelated area overflow (ala `allocA` above).

Comment: @ensc : I'm using your formula. That seems like a reasonable way to calculate it. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
inline static size_t round_up(size_t val, size_t align) {
    return (val + align - 1) / align * align;
}
```

and use it then like

```
static size_t const buffer_size = round_up(sizeof MyObject, page_size);
```

First function is typically implemented as a macro to use it in const context.  It assumes sane values (e.g. `align != 0` and `val + align` must not overflow).